# How do I read an int from command line in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

```
any choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 5: ");
```

I cannot seem to cast the input to an int.

Both check and match gives the same error

```
var intChoice = <int>choice;
match intChoice {
    int value => c = value;
    error err => io:println("error: " + err.message);
}
```

and

```
c = check <int>choice;
```

gives

```
error: 'string' cannot be cast to 'int'
```

I looked into https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-conversion.html and also studied https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io.html#readln but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it is a bug in the `any -> int` conversion.

If you change the choice variable type to `string` or change the variable definition statement to assignment statement using `var`, both approaches will works. Please refer the below example.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main(string... args) {
    // Change the any to string or var here.
    string choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 5: ");
    int c = check <int>choice;
    io:println(c);

    var intChoice = <int>choice;
    match intChoice {
        int value => io:println(value);
        error err => io:println("error: " + err.message);
    }
}
```

**Update** - As @supun has mentioned below, it is not a bug in `any->int` conversion, it is an implementation detail which I was not aware of.

Comment: Cool, that worked! Thanks a lot. Hope the bug will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Yes, it will be fixed as soon as possible :)

Comment: This answer is not correct. As explained by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782170/supun-setunga `io:readln()` function returns a `string`, therefore you have to first convert the string to int.

Answer (score 2):

The current behavior is actually correct and infact is not a bug. Let me explain the behavior.

When you read an input as `any choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 5: ");` the `choice` variable is of type `any` and it would contain a `string` value. However, the way `any` to `typeX` (in this case `int`) works is that, it will check whether the actual value inside the any-typed variable is of `typeX` (int), and if so, then do the conversion.

In this case, the actual value inside the any-typed variable  `choice` is `string`. Now if we try to convert this to `int` it will fail, for the reason that it does not contain an integer inside. So the correct aproach is to first get the string value inside the any-type variable, and then convert the string to int in a second step. See the below example:

```
import ballerina/io;

function main(string... args) {
    any choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 5: ");
    string choiceStr = <string>choice;
    int choiceInt = check <int> choiceStr;
    io:println(choiceInt);
}
```

But of course, reading the cmd input directly to a string like: `string choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 5: ");` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Ballerina `swan lake`, instead of casting, you can use `int:fromString()` method from inbuilt [int package](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/#/ballerina/lang.int/1.1.0) to convert a string to an integer.

```
function typeConversionTest() {
    string input = io:readln("Enter your input: ");
    int|error number = int:fromString(input);

    if(number is error) {
        io:println("Error occurred in conversion");
    } else {
        // Fine
    }
}
```