# How to convert a string to an int?

Tags: ballerina

According to [type conversion](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-conversion.html) example a string to int conversion is made with `int.convert()`. However in Ballerina 1.0.0 that doesn't work:

```
$ ballerina version
Ballerina 1.0.0
Language specification 2019R3
$ cat test.bal 
public function main() {
    string x = "42";
    int|error y = int.convert(x);
}
$ ballerina build test.bal 
Compiling source
        test.bal
error: .::test.bal:3:19: undefined function 'convert'
$
```

Also `<int>` as mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668193/272735) here in SO doesn't work either:

```
$ ballerina version
Ballerina 1.0.0
Language specification 2019R3
$ cat test.bal 
public function main() {
    string x = "42";
    int|error y = <int>x;
}
$ ballerina build test.bal 
Compiling source
        test.bal
error: .::test.bal:3:19: incompatible types: 'string' cannot be cast to 'int'
$
```

Comment: Could you try something like this: ```int val = check <int>strVal;``` I'm no expert in ballerina but its something I found online.  try using ```check``` prior to the cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Ballerina `swan lake` release onward, you can simply do the type conversion. No additional imports are required.

```
public function main() {
    string x = "42";
    int|error y = int:fromString(x);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ballerina v1.0 and later, you can convert `string` to `int` as follows:

```
import ballerina/lang.'int as langint;

public function main() {
    string x = "42";
    int|error y = langint:fromString(x);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Documentation available in [fromString](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/lang.int/functions.html#fromString) Somehow I missed that in the first reading ...

Comment: You can also import the builtin int package like this. `import ballerina/lang.'int;` and refer to functions as `int | error y = 'int:fromString(x);`. The identifiers start with `'` are called delimited identifiers. One use case would be to deal with keyword conflicts.